# Unable to deploy grafana using helm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, helm, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to grafana and prometheus, started working on it from last few days. I'm having some issues. I build a new grafana image and I am using the official helm repo to install it. On using the official image its wotking but on using my image the Pod is showing error. `Failed to pull image "my-repository/grafana:9.4.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/my-repository/grafana:9.4.1": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/my-repository/grafana:9.4.1": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed` On checking I understood that I need to add imagePullSecret but after add that too i'm having the issue. This is where I have added image pull secret

```
#Overrides the Grafana image tag whose default is the chart appVersion 
 tag: "9.4.1" 
 sha: ""
 pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
#Optionally specify an array of imagePullSecrets.
 #Secrets must be manually created in the namespace.
 #ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/
 #Can be templated.
 #pullSecrets:
 #- myRegistrKeySecretName
imagePullSecrets:
-name: secretname
```

What might be the issue here, any insights will be helpful

Tried adding docker secret with few indentation but still having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the YAML you have pasted the `pullSecrets` line and the `- myRegistrKeySecretName` lines are commented (with `#`); if you have used exactly what you have pasted, that would be the source of the issue.

Otherwise, I would check the following:

1. you have actually pushed the image to docker.io with the same name and tag
2. the ImagePullSecret is actually valid
3. You have named it correctly in the spec (e.g., `myRegistrKeySecretName` seems to have a typo)

Comment: Thanks for the insights, the problem was I gave `imagePullSecret` instead of `pullSecret`.